# Randomize cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a formula to randomize a column of data which keeps each item represented only once (has the same items)?

So:

```
APPLES 
PEARS
BERRIES
```

Might come out as

```
PEARS
BERRIES
APPLES
```

Randbetween formulas no good here, as you might get two 'PEAR's.

Comment: @pnuts thanks. How would you ensure there are no duplicates or missing values?

Comment: @pnuts ah I see you mean putting random numbers and using them to sort. My only problem with that is it is a hassle to do if I'm sorting the list on a regular basis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new "randomize range" feature available in the context menu after selecting a range:

[image: randomize]]

---

The following approach implements the idea of pnuts, but without creating a column filled with random numbers:

```
=query({A2:A20, arrayformula(randbetween(0, 1e20 + row(A2:A20)))}, "select Col1 order by Col2", 0)
```

Here A2:A20 is the range to be permuted. The `arrayformula` generates a random integer for each. The `query` sorts the array by those random integers, but does not put the random numbers in the spreadsheet.

The entropy of `randbetween` is 64 bits, so collisions are extremely unlikely. And even if two random numbers happen to be equal, that will not generate repetitions; *sorting* by whatever column never does that. It only means the corresponding pair of entries will appear in their original order.

Comment: Just noticed that there is now a 'randomise range' option if you right click on a selected group of cells.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this while looking for a formula to generate a set of random unique integers and ended up devising my own, so I'm leaving it here for anyone else looking for the same:

`=SORT(SEQUENCE(A$1),RANDARRAY(A$1),FALSE)` where `A$1` is the count of integers to generate (expressed here as a cell reference because I like to create sheets where I can input a number in a cell rather than changing the formula, but this can of course be just a number.)

This can be expanded by adding the three other fields to `SEQUENCE` as explained in the function's documentation, or by wrapping it in an `ARRAYCONSTRAIN` to limit the count of entries returned without changing the minimum or maximum values of the generated entries. Hope all this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I adopted a similar approach to user6655984 before I found this post.

RANDARRAY seemed to be a neat call once solution.

I had similar demands. Formula based, randomized return order, ability to have only unique records or not as the whim took me.

Right clicking to randomize range meant user interaction I didn't want and the data is dynamic.

I built in the random numbers into a query data range on the fly.

I get the flexibility of query (can easily expand the range, add returned columns filter criteria etc), I don't have to show the random numbers at all and can wrap it in UNIQUE if desired, it re-randomizes with each recalc.

Have some data in column A2:A.

To see the inline data range.
={RANDARRAY(ROWS($A$2:$A)),$A$2:$A}

Query (inc duplicates), filter out empty.
=QUERY({RANDARRAY(ROWS($A$2:$A)),$A$2:$A},"SELECT Col2 WHERE COL2<>'' ORDER BY Col1 ",0)

Same but wrapped by unique.
=UNIQUE(QUERY({RANDARRAY(ROWS($A$2:$A)),$A$2:$A},"SELECT Col2 WHERE COL2<>'' ORDER BY Col1 ",0))

Hope it helps someone, even if years later. :)

Matt